# sms delivery message with phone number

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I tried to send group sms and it works fine. But, I want to know which numbers are received my sms on delivered status:

For know delivered status I used below code:

```
public class SMSdelivered extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS DELIVERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               //want to display mobile number tooo
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS NoT DELIVERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Currently **SMS DELIVERED** message displayed fine. But, here I want to display mobile number of delivered target. How can I get delivered target mobile  number using broadcast receiver??

Any idea??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could attach an extra to the `Intent` used to create the Delivered `PendingIntent` with the addressee's number, then retrieve it in your `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
Intent delivered = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED);
delivered.putExtra("addressee", number);
PendingIntent pendingDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, delivered, 0);
```

In `onReceive()`:

```
String number = intent.getStringExtra("addressee");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried this already but, intent.getStringExtra  returns null value..

Comment: `PendingIntent`s can be reused. Try calling `getBroadcast()` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` as the last parameter.